# Disable auto saving in Sharepoint online document library file properties change

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate

I would like to disable the autosave feature in the SP online document library file properties and like to have save button. Basically I want to trigger email after filling all properties but due to this auto save feature, when I fill one field and hop on other one, email keeps triggering for all fields, so I want to know the alternate solution.

Let me know if this is possible, I'm open to other suggestions also. Basically I want to have single power automate trigger once the file properties are updated.

Comment: Did you tried customizing the forms using Power Apps?

Comment: I don't see any option, please suggest if there is any.